# TableView Cell value mandatory fill check Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, validation

I want to implement cell value check on tableview cell for specific rows ( only to those fields which are mandatory) so alert generate or print command, cell row background color will be set to red and user must have to fill that values before posting values to Server. Which function I have to use for it to check cell value status? Also I am using sections and rows structure in tableView.
For posting changes to server I am using button. Guidance suggestions required.

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: @SatishA not yet. Just give me little suggestion about it

Comment: @SatishA simplest way I have implemented but need good accurate way to validate cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Save temporary data about cells which have mandatory fields to be filled.

2.Using this data, check whether user filled or not in below method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

3.Keep updating temporary data whenever user interacts with cells.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you yes I will follow the pattern  :)

Answer (score 1):

write your validation check logic code in:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }
```

and when you want to check just reload tableview